# jQuery equivalent for window.document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript-framework

Does anyone know the jQuery equivalent for `window.document.write('')` in javascript?
Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This will add the string "hello" right before the body closing tag. Not exactly the behavior of `write`, but you can do this to any element to get the content to appear where you want it.

```
$(document.body).append('hello');
```

Also available are `prepend(content)` and `replaceWith(content)` for all your insertion needs!

Comment: Of course if you just want to replace the entire body, why not:
document.body.innerHTML = '...' which is less typing and doesn't need several thousand lines of library code to make it work.

Comment: @ctcherry This solution does not apply to scripts, only to texts.

Answer (score 20):

First, jQuery *is* JavaScript, it is just a library of functions to make coding easier.

Second, you should avoid the use of `document.write`.  You should use jQuery to append the text to the DOM element you want.

Example:

```
$('#myDiv').append('some new text')
```

Comment: +1 @Rocket ... Thanks for your suggestion ... I know that jQuery is a javascript library but the reason why I am looking for the jQuery equivalent is that I would like to write cross-browser compatible codes as far as I can.

Comment: @Kyaw: There is no "jQuery equivalent" of `document.write`, that doesn't make any sense.  You don't *need* jQuery to write cross-browser code, but it sure helps.

Comment: @Kyaw: For somethings, vanilla JavaScript works just fine, for others jQuery is the way to go.  It all depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this example:

```
table = $('#flightTypeEditTemplate').clone();
table.attr('id','');
document.write(table.html());`
```